# Trying to predict, prediction value greater than 0.5 it will be positive prediction (1) , under 0.5 value as 0 ,negative , but having problem in loop

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, model, predict

After training the model , evaluating prediction that is on dtype=float32.

```
y_pred = model.predict(x_test)
y_pred

array([[0.952564  ],
       [0.40119413],
       [0.8223132 ],
       ...,
       [0.03289893],
       [0.16677496],
       [0.882395  ]], dtype=float32)

result = model.evaluate(np.asarray(x_test), np.asarray(y_test))  
loss = result[0]
accuracy = result[1]
print(f"[+] Accuracy: {accuracy*100:.2f}%")
```

so , for this i have float32 but 1 for positive & 0 for neg, for this i have some issue , so i am trying to do, make it float32 to int32 & a loop  that if value is greater than 0.5 then it will count as 1 & if less than 0.5 then count as 0 means neg.
the loop i tried :

```
y_pred = model.predict(x_test)
y_pred ( for i in range(len(y_pred)):
  if y_pred[i][0] >= 0.5:
    y_pred[i][0] = int(1)
  else:
    y_pred[i][0] = 0



print(y_pred[0]) )
```

error is : invalid syntax .

can anyone help to sort out this one ?

Comment: Where exactly is the invalid syntax error?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: i think , my loop & conditions how im putting is wrong way !

Comment: File "<ipython-input-61-2bb03d0765e7>", line 4
    for i in range(len(y_pred)):
      ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like you should use y_pred[0][i]. The array looks to be 2d with only one sub array, so [0][i] should be used. Also, if the code is exactly what is written, i think

```
y_pred ( for i in range(len(y_pred)):
```

should be

```
for i in range(len(y_pred)):
```

Comment: it worked bro . the output is :
array([[1.],
       [0.],
       [0.],
       ...,
       [0.],
       [0.],
       [1.]], dtype=float32)
now how can i convert this dtype float32 to int ?

Comment: First if my answer worked you should mark it accepted. Second, to convert from float32 to int you can just use `number = int(number)`